# Remove a duplicate object with a specific key value from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the below Array

```
[
    {
        "membershipId": "ckktojfvl2510541qu2xlfli79q",
        "key": "ckkt9j5uq59711qu2hod0pgln",
        "isUser": true,
        "firstName": "Jennifer",
        "lastName": "Lopez",
        "name": "Jennifer Lopez",
        "DOB": "12/31/1969",
        "age": 51,
        "email": "jlo@me.com",
    },
    {
        "membershipId": "ckotgsxdz107481p2vo6r0mb0l",
        "key": "ckotgs3xo56081p2v2ek518pb",
        "isUser": true,
        "firstName": "Richard",
        "lastName": "Rizk",
        "name": "Richard Rizk",
        "DOB": "Invalid date",
        "age": "-",
        "email": "nadia@me.com",
        
    },
    {
        "membershipId": undefined,
        "key": "ckotgs3xo56081p2v2ek518pb",
        "isUser": true,
        "firstName": "Richard",
        "lastName": "Rizk",
        "name": "Richard Rizk",
        "DOB": "Invalid date",
        "age": "-",
        "email": "nadia@me.com",
        
    },
    {
        "membershipId": undefined,
        "key": "ckothigbd244581p2vfy5tihls",
        "isUser": false,
        "firstName": "Profile",
        "lastName": "Last",
        "name": "Profile Last",
        "DOB": "05/17/1986",
        "age": 35,
        "email": "",
        
    }
]
```

The array has four objects, however, two of them are the same in a way.

I need to remove the duplicate that has a membershipId equals to UNDEFINED and keep the other one.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you just want the objects whose `membershipId` are not `undefined` then `arr.filter(({ membershipId }) => membershipId)`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how you can remove elements with undefined `membershipId` if there is another element with the same key and defined `membershipId`. It creates an array with all keys where `membershipId` is not undefined. Then creates another array with elements where `membershipId` is not undefined or the key does not exist in the previous array (which means there is no duplicate with defined `membershipId`).

```js
let data = [
    {
        "membershipId": "ckktojfvl2510541qu2xlfli79q",
        "key": "ckkt9j5uq59711qu2hod0pgln",
        "isUser": true,
        "firstName": "Jennifer",
        "lastName": "Lopez",
        "name": "Jennifer Lopez",
        "DOB": "12/31/1969",
        "age": 51,
        "email": "jlo@me.com",
    },
    {
        "membershipId": "ckotgsxdz107481p2vo6r0mb0l",
        "key": "ckotgs3xo56081p2v2ek518pb",
        "isUser": true,
        "firstName": "Richard",
        "lastName": "Rizk",
        "name": "Richard Rizk",
        "DOB": "Invalid date",
        "age": "-",
        "email": "nadia@me.com",
        
    },
    {
        "membershipId": undefined,
        "key": "ckotgs3xo56081p2v2ek518pb",
        "isUser": true,
        "firstName": "Richard",
        "lastName": "Rizk",
        "name": "Richard Rizk",
        "DOB": "Invalid date",
        "age": "-",
        "email": "nadia@me.com",
        
    },
    {
        "membershipId": undefined,
        "key": "ckothigbd244581p2vfy5tihls",
        "isUser": false,
        "firstName": "Profile",
        "lastName": "Last",
        "name": "Profile Last",
        "DOB": "05/17/1986",
        "age": 35,
        "email": "",
        
    }
]

let keys = data.filter(e=>e.membershipId!==undefined).map(e=>e.key)

let result = data.filter(e=>(e.membershipId!==undefined || !keys.includes(e.key)))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
var data = [
    {
        "membershipId": "ckktojfvl2510541qu2xlfli79q",
        "key": "ckkt9j5uq59711qu2hod0pgln",
        "isUser": true,
        "firstName": "Jennifer",
        "lastName": "Lopez",
        "name": "Jennifer Lopez",
        "DOB": "12/31/1969",
        "age": 51,
        "email": "jlo@me.com",
    },
    {
        "membershipId": "ckotgsxdz107481p2vo6r0mb0l",
        "key": "ckotgs3xo56081p2v2ek518pb",
        "isUser": true,
        "firstName": "Richard",
        "lastName": "Rizk",
        "name": "Richard Rizk",
        "DOB": "Invalid date",
        "age": "-",
        "email": "nadia@me.com",
        
    },
    {
        "membershipId": undefined,
        "key": "ckotgs3xo56081p2v2ek518pb",
        "isUser": true,
        "firstName": "Richard",
        "lastName": "Rizk",
        "name": "Richard Rizk",
        "DOB": "Invalid date",
        "age": "-",
        "email": "nadia@me.com",
        
    },
    {
        "membershipId": undefined,
        "key": "ckothigbd244581p2vfy5tihls",
        "isUser": false,
        "firstName": "Profile",
        "lastName": "Last",
        "name": "Profile Last",
        "DOB": "05/17/1986",
        "age": 35,
        "email": "",
        
    }
];
console.log(data.filter((item)=>item.membershipId));
```